# CSS Transition timing of two separate elements off in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-transitions

How can I fix this timing issue in chrome? In firefox, the closing animation goes smoothly but in chrome the two elements are off. I cannot place the elements in one container to transition.

[image]

notice the white border between the off canvas and the button in the slide. They are a bit off.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var OffCanvasWidget = {
        options: {
            id: 'OffCanvasWidget',
            trigger: $('[data-offcanvas-trigger]'),
            close: $('[data-offcanvas-close]')
        },

        init: function () {
            this.addListeners();
        },
        addListeners: function () {
            var that = this;
            this.options.trigger.on('click', function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                that.toggleOffCanvas();
            });
        },
        toggleOffCanvas: function () {
            $('body').toggleClass('offcanvas-show');
        }
    };
    OffCanvasWidget.init();
});
```

```css
.trigger {
    transition: transform .7s ease;
    display: inline-block;
    transform: rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -90deg) perspective(1px) scale(1.001);
    position: fixed;
    right: -22px;
    top: 30vh;
}

.offcanvas-show .trigger {
    transform: translateX(-218px) rotate3d(0, 0, 1, -90deg) perspective(1px) scale(1.001);
}

.offcanvas {
    transform: translateX(100%);
    position: fixed;
    transition: transform .7s ease;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: auto;
    width: 200px;
}
.offcanvas-show .offcanvas {
     transform: translateX(0);
}

.trigger, .offcanvas {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" class="trigger" data-offcanvas-trigger>Follow us</a>
<div class="offcanvas">
    
</div>
```

Comment: Why not just make the 'tab' element a little wider so it 'underlaps' the tray enough so as to not notice any gap.

Comment: oh boy, why didn't I think about that. Thank you! Post this as answer and I'll upvote and accept it

Comment: In chrome ther's at least 1px gap in between the 2 elements when closed. (-23 or -24 px might do better), then, you may take a look at  `will-change: transform;` https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/w/will-change/ if that's any help to make it smoother.

Comment: tried will-change already. Doesn't do much for my usecase

Comment: okay, toobad, transition still seems jumpy in chrome ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just make the 'tab' element a little wider so it 'underlaps' the tray enough so as to not notice any gap :)